# After reading from socket can't write

Tags: java, sockets, bufferedreader

I have client and server server site. Server is working good but client site when i'm trying to read is not.

But when I remove this code it works:

```
while((read = br.readLine()) != null){
    System.out.println("in reading");
    finale += read;
    output.setText(finale);
}           
br.close();
```

Here is the complete code:

```
try{
    Socket connection = new Socket("localhost",PORT);
    PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(connection.getOutputStream()));
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
    pw.println("hi connection estabilished");
    pw.flush();
    String str,read = "",finale = "";
    while(connection.isConnected()){
        System.out.println("start");
        if(zapis == true){
            str = input.getText();
            pw.println(str);
            pw.flush();
            input.setText("");
            zapis = false;
        }
        System.out.println("top of the reading");
        while((read = br.readLine()) != null){
            System.out.println("in reading");
            finale += read;
            output.setText(finale);
        }           
        br.close();
    }
} catch(IOException e) { 
    System.out.println("error " + e); 
}
```

This is just class for listenning action of my button

```
class Listener implements ActionListener{

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    Main.zapis = true;
}   
}
```

Comment: can you try this  PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(connection.getOutputStream()),true);

Comment: What do you mean "it's not working"? Any exception?

Comment: @ThomasUhrig I can't write to that socket

Comment: Again: Any exception? Does the program block? Does your PC take fire? "Can't write" doesn't provide any information.

Comment: No exceptions nothing no errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, you open `br` outside of the loop `while(connection.isConnected()){` but you close it in the loop.

You should try to write your last block (the one that make it works when you remove it) as :

```
    System.out.println("top of the reading");
    while((read = br.readLine()) != null){
        System.out.println("in reading");
        finale += read;
        output.setText(finale);
    }           
}
br.close();
```

with the close **outside** of the loop.